# How to show same field based on an or condition on alpaca by binding a field to multiple dependencies

Tags: conditional-statements, forms, alpacajs

I am using alpacajs to render an HTML form. My requirement is to show certain fields based on a checkbox. there are three checkboxes in my form and I want to show some fields if any of the checkboxes are checked.

I went through alpaca documentation on [conditional dependencies](http://www.alpacajs.org/docs/api/conditional-dependencies.html) and couldn't find a soution to my problem. I can solve this by creating same fields with different names but that's against [dry principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

My code looks like below.

```
"myCheckBox1": {
    "type": "boolean"
},
"myCheckBox2": {
    "type": "boolean"
},
"usernameField": {
    "label": "Username *",
    "order": 6,
    "type": "string"
    "disallowOnlyEmptySpaces": true,
    "showMessages": false,
    "disallowEmptySpaces": true,
}
```

I want to show usernameField if either of myCheckBox1 or myCheckBox2 is checked. I altered schema to show conditional dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
  "usernameField": [
    "myCheckBox1"
  ],
  "usernameField": [
    "myCheckBox2"
  ]
}
```

But that consider only last given condition ie, it will display usernameField only if myCheckBox2 is checked and does not consider myCheckBox1. I tried below code also:

```
"dependencies": {
  "usernameField": [
    "myCheckBox1", "myCheckBox2"
  ]
}
```

But that evaluates to an `and condition`. Is there a way to show same field using different dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you don't use a group of checkboxes using enum type like the following :

```
// schema
"check": {
    "title": "Select...",
    "type": "string",
    "enum": ["First", "Second"]
},
...
// options
"check": {
    "type": "checkbox"
}
```

Then you use conditional dependencies like this:

```
"username": {
   "dependencies": {
      "check": [
          'First', // if First is selected
          'Second', // if Second is selected
          'First,Second' // if both First and Second are selected
      ] 
   }
}
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/kjnar5kj/) for this.

Please tell me if this isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Also,is there a way to show text box below checkbox that is checked?

Comment: Hmm in Alpaca standards I think that will be impossible because we used a grouped checkbox, you can consider that grouped checkbox is a one field. But you can hack into the generated form and make this possible by using jquery in the postRender function.